# Como criar uma view no mysql pegando dados de 3 tabelas e repetindo as colunas diferentes no resultado?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho as tabelas:

```
+----------Tabela-1--------+
id | nome   |  cnpj   | qtd1
1  | carlos | 0563233 |   4 
+--------------------------+

+----------Tabela-2--------+
id | nome   |  cnpj   | qtd2
1  | carlos | 0563233 |   6 
+--------------------------+

+----------Tabela-3--------+
id | nome   |  cnpj   | qtd3
1  | carlos | 0563233 |   8 
+--------------------------+
```

Gostaria de fazer um comando sql para gerar uma única tabela colocando as colunas com nome diferentes uma do lado da outra, por exemplo:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
 id  | nome   |    cnpj    | qtd1  | qtd2  |  qtd3
  1  | carlos | 0563233    |   4   |  6    |    8
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Comment: O que você já tentou? Poste um trecho de SQL que você estava tentando usar

Comment: Já tentei fazer um select de cada tabela e depois usar o union para juntar, só que ele não mostrar as colunas diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta fazer o join entre as tabelas pelo campo que elas tem em comum

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.nome,
  T1.cnpj,
  T1.qtd1,
  T2.qtd2,
  T3.qtd3
FROM
  tabela1 T1
  INNER JOIN tabela2 T2 on (T1.id = T2.id)
  INNER JOIN tabela3 T3 on (T1.id = T3.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

você pode usar também o LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.nome, t1.cnpj, t1.qtd1, t2.qtd2, t3.qtd3 FROM tabela1 t1 LEFT JOIN tabela2 t2 on (t1.id = t2.id) LEFT JOIN tabela3 t3 on (t1.id = t3.id)
```

ou ainda com o WHERE  para fazer a condição entre tabelas

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.nome, t1.cnpj, t1.qtd1, t2.qtd2, t3.qtd3 FROM tabela1 t1, tabela2 t2, tabela3 t3 WHERE t1.id = t2.id and t1.id = t3.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu não usuario nem [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) nem [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp), eu usaria de cara um [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) (igual primeira resposta do @Flaviano Silva), porque, se as tabelas subsequentes não tiverem os dados da relação eu trago o valor da `tabela1` e trabalho os outros valores com *0* ou qualquer de sua preferência.

```sql
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.nome,
  T1.cnpj,
  ifnull(T1.qtd1, 0) AS qtd1,
  ifnull(T2.qtd2, 0) AS qtd2,
  ifnull(T3.qtd3, 0) AS qtd3
FROM
  tabela1 T1
  LEFT JOIN tabela2 T2 on (T1.id = T2.id)
  LEFT JOIN tabela3 T3 on (T1.id = T3.id);
```

***Exemplo:*** **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90ef89/2)**

Answer (score 3):

Todas as outras respostas partem do princípio que nas 3 tabelas cada pessoa tem sempre o mesmo ID. Isso é verdadeiro no exemplo postado, mas não tenho tanta certeza de que seja assim no banco de dados real. Por isso, sugiro também um `LEFT JOIN`, mas pelo campo CNPJ em vez do ID.

Adaptando a query do Harry Potter:

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.nome,
  T1.cnpj,
  ifnull(T1.qtd1, 0) AS qtd1,
  ifnull(T2.qtd2, 0) AS qtd2,
  ifnull(T3.qtd3, 0) AS qtd3
FROM
  tabela1 T1
  LEFT JOIN tabela2 T2 on (T1.cnpj = T2.cnpj)
  LEFT JOIN tabela3 T3 on (T1.cnpj = T3.cnpj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que colocou "MySQL" como tag da sua pergunta e falou em "gerar uma única tabela colocando as **colunas com nome diferentes** uma do lado da outra", você pode usar os joins naturais que casam as colunas de mesmo nome para você, fazendo o que pediu:

```
select * 
from Tabela1
natural left join Tabela2
natural left join Tabela3
```